# What are some data encoding options for transmission over a lossy network?

Tags: networking, encoding, data-integrity, loss

A long time ago, I was reading up on a cellular encoding technology for transmitting lossy data. If I recall it padded the data or something to that effect, or provided it with some kind of redundancy so that only 60% of the transmission had to be received in order to get the complete information sent. I cannot remember the name of the encoding.

Anyways, I am in need of something I can use to encode data which would have similar redundant/resilient properties, IE transmission over a lossy UDP network, radio, etc.

Does anyone have an ideas of an appropriate encoding scheme for data integrity in a lossy network? Especially perhaps something I can implement using Python, however Python is not required.

Comment: Won't the network library you use handle this for you?

Comment: Considering looking at [Reed-Solomon Error Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction).

Comment: @WaleedKhan I think it's assuming that transmission is lossy over an *non-reliable* layer (where ack/retranmission is not feasible or efficient) .. or the answer would be "TCP" and the question would go nowhere.

Comment: My mind jumped immediately to the old [PAR2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) format.  Not sure if that would work for you or not.

Comment: It seems that most EC (e.g. Reed-Solomon) focuses on intrapacket corruption: which is dealt with at the hardware level.

Comment: Pretty sure that hardware level, won't allow for 60% complete UDP messages. It's all or nothing. You'd have to write your own messaging/EC and use UDP to ensure that gets through, but I think that simple awk/resend should suffice.

Comment: @Alan Which is where I think the idea of *redundancy* (spread across packets) sounds interesting .. so that retransmissions, while still required for 100% delivery, can be mitigated.

Comment: @user2864740 Interesting, yes. Though the tradeoff (complexity of implementation vs network bandwidth waste) would only really make sense in the tightest of scenarios, like perhaps on the battlefield, or in space.

Comment: I am not a guru in this field. I extremely appreciate everyone's input on implementation of this type of encoding. This is what I was looking to implement! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction - In particular, what I remembered reading was Hamming(7,4)! I could not for the life of me remember what I had read.

Answer (score 1):

Back in my military simulation days, we used a flavor of [Reliable UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol). While not a formal standard, there are implementations out in the wild.

The idea is to add awknowledgements to packets, along with the ability to resend missed/dropped packets.

You could add a simple CRC or hash to the packet itself to verify the integrity, if you're worried about scrambled bits.

Comment: Re-inventing TCP isn't very fun. Also it seems that for very lossy (e.g. 60% loss) networks it would be more efficient to use more data redundancy to minimize retransmissions.

Comment: RUDP isn't TCP. The whole idea of RUDP is with a few additional features, you can get reliable transmission without the extra overhead with TCP.

Comment: *sigh* It wasn't meant to be taken literally. Anyway, neither *adds* redundancy or correction (beside from ack/retrans) abilities into the stream. (Rather, the RTO *could* use better techniques when transmitting to minimize the back chatter.)